# Java transformer, xml:space and indentation difference between Java 8 en Java 11

Tags: java

In our application we're using the below (partially) code to format the XML.
This works fine on Java 8 but no longer on Java 11.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

In our XML there is a XML element named 'condition' with the attribute xml:space="preserve".
Everything XML elements before this tag is well formatted, all the elements (no children) after this condition tag stay on the same line (no indentation).

We're using the transformer factory 'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl' when using the 'org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl' it works better.

This is probably introduced in Java 9 because that had a lot of changes in the transformer part. I could not find any issue or solution addressing the above part.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem (or is this the new way that preserve should work)?

Comment: XML related dependencies were deprecated in jdk9 and completely removed in jdk11. 
You need to include  `jakarta.xml.bind` in your decencies and and use it.

Comment: I think in open adopt JDK 11, there is com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl present when using the transformer. Probably there is a bug in the ToStream class of open adopt

Comment: It has been fixed within https://bugs-stage.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8265073